In my React project manager app, why does the edit (input) field stay open when switching projects?
Apologies ahead of time if i do not fully explain my issue. I will try my best. I have a Project Manager app with the ability to add new projects with project details like, Title, Due Date, & Description. All added projects are shown in an aside on the left and project details on the right. Selecting a particular project will render it's details on the right side of the App. I recently added the ability to click on a "detail" text to edit it - essentially i added an onClick event to open that content detail in an input field.
It works mostly as expected, the correct field is opened, the content can be edited, and saved as expected - updating my Master Projects object in the context store.
However, if the edit (input) field is left open and the project is switched to another project, the input field remains open when it should not be and i need to fix this.
This is my EditableField.jsx component:
import { useState, useRef, useContext, forwardRef } from "react";
import { PMContext } from "../store/pm_context";

const EditableField = forwardRef(function EditableField(
  { data, type, edit, children, ...props },
  ref
) {
  const { editProject } = useContext(PMContext);
  const [fieldInput, setFieldInput] = useState();
  const [isEdit, setEdit] = useState(false);

  function handleEditProjectField() {
    setFieldInput(data[type]);
    setEdit((prevState) => {
      return !prevState;
    });
  }

  function handleChange(event) {
    const input = event.target.value;
    setFieldInput(input);
  }

  function handleSaveProjectField() {
    if (fieldInput.trim() === "") {
      modal.current.open();
      return;
    }
    editProject(fieldInput, type);
    setEdit((prevState) => {
      return !prevState;
    });
  }

  let inputField =
    type === "description" ? (
      <textarea
        ref={ref}
        className="input-field"
        type="text"
        value={fieldInput}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    ) : type === "dueDate" ? (
      <input
        ref={ref}
        className="input-field"
        type="date"
        value={fieldInput}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    ) : (
      <input
        ref={ref}
        className="input-field"
        type="text"
        value={fieldInput}
        onChange={handleChange}
      />
    );

  let editField = isEdit ? (
    <div className="editable-field">
      {inputField}
      <button
        id={data.id}
        onClick={() => handleSaveProjectField(data.id)}
        className="save"
      >
        Save
      </button>
    </div>
  ) : (
    <div className="editable-field" onClick={handleEditProjectField} {...props}>
      {children}
    </div>
  );

  return <>{editField}</>;
});

export default EditableField;

I thought, by setting the default state of isEdit to false, when the component was re-rendered isEdit would be false so only the {children} would be rendered in the editable-field div but this is not the case and {inputField} persists.
I have set up a codesandbox with the running app here: CodeSandbox Link
Any help on how to make this function correctly and why is greatly appreciated.

The default state of the useState hook is initialized during the mounting stage of the component. After re-rendering, which happens in your case when you select a different project, the <ProjectDetails /> component is not being un-mounted but re-rendered thus, the state of the children components EditableField remains the same. Will a react component reset its state when it re-renders?
A simple fix is to add state reset logic to the useEffect where the project id would be in a dependencies array:
// EditableField.tsx

useEffect(() => {
  setEdit(false);
}, [data.id]) 


Answer much appreciated @Anton! This solved the problem.
